# Statement of comparability for German blue card

Tags: blue-card

I am applying for German Blue card. My University is listed in Anabin database however my qualification which is Masters of Engineering in Electronics and Communication  is not listed . However, Masters of Engineering in Electronics is listed . Do I need to apply for individual statement of comparability to ZAB.

Comment: This is very likely the same thing and they just changed the name. I would suggest you contact the Foreign student/alumni department of the uni for advice